# I want to prove that for every $a > 1$, the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(n/a^n\right)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> I want to prove that for every $a > 1$, the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(n/a^n\right)=0$

I was given the hint that $a=(\sqrt{a})^2$ but I don't even know how that is useful to me. I know that for proving the limit is $0$, I want to prove $|a_n|<\epsilon$. I also know that I should use a $N>n$, but I'm confused as to where they all come together.

Comment: This isn't true for $0\lt a\le 1$

Comment: Unless there is a typo in the headline the claim is not true. E.g for $a= 1/2$ you get $n/a^n = 2^n n$, which tends to $\infty$. Did you intend to write $a> 1$?

Comment: I changed it for $a>1$ because you are right and there was a typo, I'm so sorry.

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = b$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n} = b$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n}{a^{2n}}=\frac{2}{a^n}\cdot\frac{n}{a^n}$. If you can prove that such $b$ exists and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^n = \infty$ then it follows that $b$ must be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, for $a>1$, you also have $\sqrt{a}>1$, so $\sqrt{a} = 1+x$ for some $x>0$. Then $a^n= (1+x)^{2n} = ((1+x)^n)^2> (1+nx)^2 $ by Bernoulli's inequality.
Can you finish the proof from here?

The claim is wrong for $a\le 1$

Comment: Wow! That was so useful thank you! I continued by saying that $(n/a^n)<n/(1+nx)^2<n/n^2$ and $n/n^2=1/n$ which converges to 0. Is that correct?

Comment: @AmélieSte-Marie Close. But you must not ignore the $x$ in the step from the second to the third term. But the main point is, in fact, to get some $n^2$ term in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

L'Hopital's rule comes to help. the derivative of $n$ is $1$. and the derivative of $a^n$ is n * a^(n-1).

Comment: There is really no need to use derivatives here.